# react Prop unique key problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Home`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

```
          {tours&&
            tours?.map((item, index) =\>
                
            )}
```

and also I try this

```
          {tours&&
            tours?.map((item, index) =\>
               
                
               
            )}
```

but the same problem is show

Comment: {tours&&
            tours?.map((item, index) =\>
               
               <CardTour key={index} {...item}/> 
               
            )}   this is the qusestion

Comment: Do you have a 'key' key in the item object?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You should have a key called 'key' in the component being displayed, same way you have a className key. For instance:

```
{tours && tours?.map((item, index) =\>
          <div key={index}></div>      
            )}
```